# Pandas: checking if a value exists in each cell of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm using python 2.7 and want to create a column depending on the existence of each value of a list in every cell.

Here's an example of data:

```
|    query      |
-----------------
| handbag woman |
| shoe man      |
| t-shirt baby  |
| watch unisex  |
| dress         |
```

I have a list of value that I want to check:

```
gender_list=['woman', 'man', 'baby', 'unisex']
```

the result that I expect:

```
|   query      |   gender
-----------------------
|   handbag    |  woman 
|   shoe       |  man      
|   t-shirt    |  baby  
|   watch      |  unisex  
|   dress      |  None
```

Here's what I have already tried:

```
for gender in gender_list:
    df['gender']=df['query'].map(lambda x : gender if (x.find(gender) != -1) else None)
    df['query']=df['query'].map(lambda x : x.replace(gender, '').strip() if (x.find(gender) != -1) else x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in pandas the best is not used loops, because slow (apply are loops under the hood) and rather use vectorized solutions.

Use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) by regex join all values by `|` and use `word boundary` for exact match:

```
gender_list=['woman', 'man', 'baby', 'unisex']
#exact match is not important
#pat = '|'.join(gender_list)
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in gender_list)
print (pat)
\bwoman\b|\bman\b|\bbaby\b|\bunisex\b

df['gender'] = df['query'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
df['query'] = df['query'].str.replace(pat, '').str.strip()
print (df)
     query  gender
0  handbag   woman
1     shoe     man
2  t-shirt    baby
3    watch  unisex
4    dress     NaN
```

Differences:

```
print (df)
           query
0  handbag woman
1      shoe many <-man change to many
2   t-shirt baby
3   watch unisex
4          dress

gender_list=['woman', 'man', 'baby', 'unisex']
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in gender_list)
df['gender'] = df['query'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
df['query'] = df['query'].str.replace(pat, '').str.strip()
print (df)
       query  gender
0    handbag   woman
1  shoe many     NaN <-many not extracted
2    t-shirt    baby
3      watch  unisex
4      dress     NaN
```

---

```
gender_list=['woman', 'man', 'baby', 'unisex']
pat = '|'.join(gender_list)
df['gender'] = df['query'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
df['query'] = df['query'].str.replace(pat, '').str.strip()
print (df)
     query  gender
0  handbag   woman
1   shoe y     man <-stay y from many
2  t-shirt    baby
3    watch  unisex
4    dress     NaN
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'query': ['handbag woman', 'shoe man', 't-shirt baby', 'watch unisex', 'dress', 'manpower']})
print (df)

df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [299]: %%timeit
     ...: pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in gender_list)
     ...: df['gender'] = df['query'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
     ...: df['query'] = df['query'].str.replace(pat, '').str.strip()
     ...: 
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 143 ms per loop

In [300]: %%timeit
     ...: gender_set = set(gender_list)
     ...: 
     ...: def gender_sep(row):
     ...:     lst = row['query'].split(' ')
     ...:     gender = next(iter(gender_set & set(lst)), None)
     ...:     return (' '.join(lst), None) if not gender else \
     ...:            (' '.join(i for i in lst if i!= gender), gender)
     ...: 
     ...: df['query'], df['gender'] = list(zip(*df.apply(gender_sep, axis=1)))
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 933 ms per loop
```

EDIT:

For more common general solution need escape regex values by `re.escape`:

```
import re

gender_list=['woman', 'man', 'baby', 'girl & boy']
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(x)) for x in gender_list)
df['gender'] = df['query'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
df['query'] = df['query'].str.replace(pat, '').str.strip()
```

Comment: I want to remove the value from the initial query too !!

Comment: your solution works fine but i still have an issue with composed values in my list:
when i apply: `df['gender'] = df['query'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)`
i got:
`Wrong number of items passed 7, placement implies 1`
ithink it's cosed by composed strings for example 'girl and boy'.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way. It's not the most efficient, but it is readable and easy to adapt / maintain.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'query': ['handbag woman', 'shoe man', 't-shirt baby', 'watch unisex', 'dress', 'manpower']})

gender_list = ['woman', 'man', 'baby', 'unisex']
gender_set = set(gender_list)

def gender_sep(row):
    lst = row['query'].split(' ')
    gender = next(iter(gender_set & set(lst)), None)
    return (' '.join(lst), None) if not gender else \
           (' '.join(i for i in lst if i!= gender), gender)

df['query'], df['gender'] = list(zip(*df.apply(gender_sep, axis=1)))

#       query  gender
# 0   handbag   woman
# 1      shoe     man
# 2   t-shirt    baby
# 3     watch  unisex
# 4     dress    None
# 5  manpower    None
```

Comment: I want to remove the value from the initial query too !!

Comment: your solution works fine but i still have an issue with the value contained in another string.
For example ‘manpower’ contains ‘man’ and I didn't want to match it.